# pop_front crashing the program

Tags: c++, list, std

I'm creating a pool of threads that cosumes a buffer and do some actions on my application. I've created a std::list m_buffer and sometimes the application crashes on the end of the buffer.
Here's my code:

```
   MyObject* myObject = 0;
   bool hasMore = true;
   while(hasMore)  
   {  
     {  
       boost::unique_lock lck(m_loadMutex1);  
       if(!m_buffer.size())  
         break;  
       myObject = m_buffer.front();  
       m_buffer.pop_front();  
       hasMore = m_buffer.size();  
     }
   }
   if(myObject)
      loadMyObject(myObject);
```

I'm sure the list never starts empty. And a lot of threads executes this piece of code at the same time. And testing it on Windows sometimes the application crashes and the debugger says it was on pop_front. But I can't believe its there because I check if the size is more than 0.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Just a side note: g++ comes with a suboptimal (and noncorformant I believe) `list::size` function that runs in linear time. Use `empty` instead.

Comment: So, why can you be sure that the list never is empty when entering the while loop? Did you try to initialize `bool hasMore = m_buffer.size() > 0;` or `bool hasMore = !m_buffer.empty();` (to respect Mark B's comment)?

Comment: Is that the only place where you pop_front()?

Comment: @Flinsch : If he accessed the `list` from outside the scope of the `unique_lock`, there could be memory corruption. There's no harm in entering the `while` loop every time because the first thing the code does after locking the mutex is `break` if the `list` is empty.

Comment: Humor me and below the lock, change your code to this: `if(!m_buffer.size()) { m_buffer.clear(); break; }`

Answer (score 0):

Set first-chance exceptions in the debugger and see what the exception is that is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way that the code as posted would contain such a problem.

Most likely somewhere ELSE you're adding or removing from the list, unprotected, at the same time this function is popping.

Alternately there could be random memory corruption. Check the size of the buffer in the debugger when the `pop_front` fails.

Comment: Can't be because I start the threads only after I finalize to add all objects in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I would review how the program terminates.  Maybe the list has been deallocated.  This could happen in a variety if ways.  For example: the list is created on the main thread, the main thread finishes and deallocates the list, and the other threads are still using the list.  I mention this particular example because I do not see any logic in the thread method above that lets each thread know it is 'shutdown' time.

Comment: Well... I've created a simple queue by myself and it stoped crashing... I still don't know what its wrong :-/